# Implementing automatic dark mode with option to change settings manually

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement dark mode on my Wordpress website. So far I've created a simple button that allows users to change theme manually which works just fine. However, now I'm trying to combine this with automatic theme detection based on user's OS settings. Here's my code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    //Create the cookie object
    var cookieStorage = {
        setCookie: function setCookie(key, value, time, path) {
            var expires = new Date();
            expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + time);
            var pathValue = '';
            if (typeof path !== 'undefined') {
                pathValue = 'path=' + path + ';';
            }
            document.cookie = key + '=' + value + ';' + pathValue + 'expires=' + expires.toUTCString();
        },
        getCookie: function getCookie(key) {
            var keyValue = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + key + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
            return keyValue ? keyValue[2] : null;
        },
        removeCookie: function removeCookie(key) {
            document.cookie = key + '=; Max-Age=0; path=/';
        }
    };

    //Click on dark mode icon. Add dark mode classes and wrappers. Store user preference through sessions
    $('.dark-mode-button').click(function() {
        //Show either moon or sun
        $('.dark-mode-button').toggleClass('active');
        //If dark mode is selected
        if ($('.dark-mode-button').hasClass('active')) {
            //Add dark mode class to the body
            $('body').addClass('dark-mode');
            cookieStorage.setCookie('MyDarkMode', 'true', 2628000000, '/');
        } else {
            $('body').removeClass('dark-mode');
            setTimeout(function() {
                cookieStorage.removeCookie('MyDarkMode');
            }, 100);
        }
    })

    //Check Storage. Display user preference 
    if (cookieStorage.getCookie('MyDarkMode')) {
        $('body').addClass('dark-mode');
        $('.dark-mode-button').addClass('active');
    }
    
    // Theme depending on system preferences    
if (window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches) {
        $('body').addClass('dark-mode');
        $('.dark-mode-button').toggleClass('active');
    }
    
    console.log(cookieStorage.getCookie());

})
```

I'm not really sure where to go from there. It should work like that: if user enters my website for the first time, theme should be automatically adjusted based on his OS settings - if it's dark, then display website in dark mode and vice versa. But if user decides to manually change theme mode via dedicated button in header, his OS settings should not be followed anymore. The code I provided does just that except for the last part - manually changed settings are not saved. Now when user changes theme manually, after page refresh it goes back to the theme picked based on his OS settings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery - Toggle dark mode using local storage and prefers-color-scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65986237/jquery-toggle-dark-mode-using-local-storage-and-prefers-color-scheme) While this question uses local storage, the basic logic used in the answer can be applied to this question. Simply substitute `cookieStorage.getCookie` for `localStorage.getItem` and `cookieStorage.setCookie` for `localStorage.setItem`.

Answer (score 0):

If you were going to have a manual override you could just make it so that the user clicks the manual override and it changes it to the opposite color mode and then it would save it in local storage that the user wants a specific color mode. Then when the color scheme changes according to the time, it will cancel it out by checking if the user has a preference or not.

If you do not know how to use local storage then you can learn how to here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Comment: Ok sorry let me fix that real quick.